# Split xml into files - method takes less memory

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xelement

I need to split my `XML` into files.
This is structure of my sample `XML`:

```
<Data Code="L6POS1">
<Lots RowVersion="464775">
   <Lot Id="5"  Quantity="10068.0000" GUID="AA616D3D-F442-6AEE-0BAB-1D13F6961C2A" />
   <Lot Id="99"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="24A9C957-EC98-85D5-8F96-0120F6E8A572" />
   <Lot Id="101"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="124D17A2-1568-DB02-4327-4669FE00F741" />
   <Lot Id="103"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="DD1730FF-27CF-1269-7AC2-3152CB6FDC46" />
   <Lot Id="105"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="1F25378F-30D4-E4E0-9939-1E9E69C806C1" />
   <Lot Id="188"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="2E860029-29B3-54C2-B8D1-0C6ABDA42DFF" />
   <Lot Id="189"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="D3C58850-BC23-E8DE-A919-09CCB3F8A1D3" />
</Lots>
```

Expected result: `FirstFile`:

```
 <Data Code="L6POS1">
 <Lots RowVersion="464775">
   <Lot Id="5"  Quantity="10068.0000" GUID="AA616D3D-F442-6AEE-0BAB-1D13F6961C2A" />
   <Lot Id="99"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="24A9C957-EC98-85D5-8F96-0120F6E8A572" />
   <Lot Id="101"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="124D17A2-1568-DB02-4327-4669FE00F741" />
   <Lot Id="103"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="DD1730FF-27CF-1269-7AC2-3152CB6FDC46" />   
</Lots>
</Data>
```

And `SecondFile`:

```
<Data Code="L6POS1">
 <Lots RowVersion="464775">
   <Lot Id="105"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="1F25378F-30D4-E4E0-9939-1E9E69C806C1" />
   <Lot Id="188"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="2E860029-29B3-54C2-B8D1-0C6ABDA42DFF" />
   <Lot Id="189"  Quantity="0.0000" GUID="D3C58850-BC23-E8DE-A919-09CCB3F8A1D3" />
</Lots>
</Data>
```

Actually I'm using:

```
   private IEnumerable<XElement> CreateXMLPackagesByType(string syncEntityName, XElement root)
    {
        var xmlList = new List<XElement>();
        IEnumerable<XElement> childNodes = root.Elements();

        var childsCount = childNodes.Count();

        var skip = 0;
        var take = ConfigurationService.MaxImportPackageSize;
        var rootAttributes = root.Attributes();
        XElement rootWithoutDescendants;
        while (skip < childsCount)
        {
            rootWithoutDescendants = new XElement(root.Name);
            rootWithoutDescendants.Add(rootAttributes);

            var elems = childNodes.Skip(skip).Take(take);
            skip += take;
            xmlList.Add(CreatePackage(rootWithoutDescendants, elems));
        }

        return xmlList;
    }


      private XElement CreatePackage(XElement type, IEnumerable<XElement> elems)
    {
        type.Add(elems);
        var root = new XElement("Data", type);
        root.Add(new XAttribute("Code", ConfigurationService.Code));
        return root;
    }
```

Unfortunately, in this way a get `OutOfMemoryException` with bigger `XML` files on older hardware.  It is better way to split `XElement`?

Comment: Consider [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You need to use a SAX parser rather than a document parser. As @Tom points out XmlReader is a good option. You could also compile it for 64bit - not the best solution - just saying :-)

Answer (score 1):

Previous comments suggesting to use a SAX parser are correct -- that way you get each event (element, etc) one at a time, and you don't have to keep anything around afterwards.

If you're absolutely certain that your data is as neatly broken into lines as your example, a quick-and-dirty method would be to not even parse, but just read a line at a time. Handle the first two, then break up the rest how you want, then handle the last two. But be really sure (in other words, *check*) that every `<Lot>` element takes up exactly one physical line; as you probably already know, there's no reason they *have* to be that way in XML in general.